# Copy/paste games from Chess StackExchange to lichess.org

Tags: pgn, lichess, fen

When I encounter an interesting question on Chess StackExchange, I would like to import that game to http://lichess.org, to be able to analyze it with Stockfish. When I use the "Copy game" option (for example from [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/33345/23857)) and paste that PGN into https://lichess.org/paste, it does not work (I get an empty board).

It seems that the problem is the `[FEN ""]` tag: if I remove it, it works. If I replace that tag with `[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]`, it also works.

Is this a bug in lichess or in stackexchange? In other words, is the empty string a valid FEN position?

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have now posted the question at https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/911/23857